# How to test code style and standards in React?

Tags: reactjs, testing

Me and my team are making a React website. We've done all the coding bits, however, I'm worried that with more people joining in, our code-base can become messy, as in:

- Improper indentation used (preferred 2 space in `.js` files)
- Extremely long lines (I'd prefer to set a limit for number of lines in a row)
- Incorrect location of CSS files: For e.g. storing `.css` files under components (I'd prefer them to be in `src/` but outside `src/components/`)
- No Warnings when running npm start.

From the little I've tested out testing libraries for React, they mostly deal with code errors. I'm aware in Android it is possible to keep checks for first two options using testing libraries. What are React/NodeJS solutions for the same?

Comment: Look into Prettier.

Comment: Code linters like Prettier might help a lot in the indentation, warnings and similar stuff but putting CSS in which project directory may come from practices and your project architecture design.

Comment: You can use prettier in your code edtor.To have linting integrated in your codebase ,you can use lint-staged that would allow the eslint checks on the files that are staged. Please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged 
This would allow the developers to make eslint changes only on those files that are edited rather than linting the complete codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Prettier to format you code with just one command in editors like Visual Studio code.

> Incorrect location of CSS files: For e.g. storing .css files under components (I'd prefer them to be in src/ but outside src/components/)

There is no way to automate this as far as I know, but this should be possible by setting the right example first and communicating your preference.

Comment: You could probably set up a rule with ESLint [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) to give warning/error when trying to import a css file from an improper location... though it would be much easier just to set a precedent and give correction in pull requests